# How to interpret /var/log output

Tags: linux, directory, ls, date, audit

I have trouble interpreting the following output from /var/log. Both lines show the same result but of different date? What does this mean?

Currently doing an audit to ensure that the directories are as restrictive as possible.

```
/var/log:
total 412234
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root root                    4096 Aug 25 04:02 .
drwxr-xr-x. 25 root root                    4096 Sep 16  2018 ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root root         4096 Aug 25 04:02 .
drwxr-xr-x. 25 root root         4096 Sep 16  2018 ..
```

The two records above are:

- one is `.` the current directory `/var/log`
- The other `..` is the parent directory. In this case `..` will be the
  parent directory of `/var/log` which is `/var`.